# adding to Maps in Java

Tags: java, loops, maps

Hi i am trying to add countries to a map see below code. I am able to input the countries but my out is not what i expected. The Set prints out 4 times where i want each country counting form 1-4 not each Set. can you help?

```
    /**
      * MY CODE SO FAR = pleae can you help
      */
    
       import java.util.*;

    class EuroGroupStages {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {

         Map<Integer, Set<String>> groupA;
         Map<Integer, Set<String>> groupB;
         Map<Integer, Set<String>> groupC;
         Map<Integer, Set<String>> groupD;
         
//public EuroGroupStages() 
//  {
    groupA = new TreeMap<>();
    groupB = new TreeMap<>();
    groupC = new TreeMap<>();
    groupD = new TreeMap<>();
//  }
         
//public void addCountries()
//  {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<String> country = new HashSet<>();
        String aCountry;
        
        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a country");
            aCountry = keyboard.next();
            country.add(aCountry);
            groupA.put(i, country);
        }
        
        System.out.println(groupA);
        
        keyboard.close();
//  }

    }
}
        
        
        {1=[England, Scotland, Czech, Croatia], 2=[England, Scotland, Czech, Croatia], 3=[England, Scotland, Czech, Croatia], 4=[England, Scotland, Czech, Croatia]}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do and I foresee some possible problems.  If you explain what you are trying to do `(e.g why four of Map<Integer,Set<String>>)` then help may be provided to solve your immediate problem and avoid potential ones.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `System.out.println(groupA);`

try to write:

```
  for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(groupA.get(i));
        }
```

for getting the value of each key in `groupA`.

**Edit:**

Here are some examples for getting the combinations of key+value:
(https://www.techiedelight.com/iterate-map-using-keyset-java/)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
 
public class Main
{
    // Program to iterate map using `keySet()` in Java
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, "One");
        map.put(2, "Two");
        map.put(3, "Three");
        map.put(4, "Four");
 
        // 1. Using an iterator
        Iterator<Integer> itr = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
            Integer key = itr.next();
            String value = map.get(key);
            System.out.println(key + "=" + value);
        }
 
        // 2. For-each loop
        for (Integer key: map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + "=" + map.get(key));
        }
 
        // 3. Java 8 - Iterator.forEachRemaining()
        map.keySet()
            .iterator()
            .forEachRemaining(key -> System.out.println(key + "=" + map.get(key)));
 
        // 4. Java 8 - Stream.forEach()
        map.keySet().stream()
            .forEach(key -> System.out.println(key + "=" + map.get(key)));
 
        // 5. Java 8 - Stream.of() + toArray() + forEach()
        Stream.of(map.keySet().toArray())
            .forEach(key -> System.out.println(key + "=" + map.get(key)));
    }
}
```

Code is compileable in java-online compiler:
(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)

One of these approaches is certainly applicable to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting each country in a set and then adding the whole set each time.  What I think you want to do is to put the countries in individual sets and add those to the map (more information would be helpful).  To do this, a new Set must be created in each iteration of the loop to hold the next country.

```
// first you can delare you maps like this.
Map<Integer, Set<String>> groupA= new TreeMap<>(); 
    
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a country");
    Set<String> country = new HashSet<>();
    country.add(keyboard.next());
    groupA.put(i, country);
}

groupA.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints something like

```
1=[USA]
2=[Canada]
3=[Norway]
4=[England]
```

And do not close the Scanner when taking input from the keyboard.